# stripe cancel subscription after end period

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments, webhooks

I have a method to cancel subscriptions like this:

```
def cancel_subscription
  customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(current_user.stripe_customer_id)
  customer.subscriptions.retrieve(current_user.subscription_id).delete(:at_period_end => true)
  current_user.subscribed = false
  if current_user.save
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Im using `(:at_period_end => true)` to cancel at the end at end date from started.

But also in my DB i have a column which is set to false or true depending on if the customer is subscribed or not:

```
current_user.subscribed = false
```

I want to change this to false after the end period. For example the customer cancels the subscription but still has 10 days left. I want `current_user.subscribed` set to false after the actual period is over and the customer is now properly unsubscribed.

Here is web hook set up:

```
def webhook
  begin
    event_json = JSON.parse(request.body.read)
    event_object = event_json['data']['object']
    #refer event types here https://stripe.com/docs/api#event_types
    case event_json['type']
      when 'invoice.payment_succeeded'
        handle_success_invoice event_object
      when 'invoice.payment_failed'
        handle_failure_invoice event_object
      when 'charge.failed'
        handle_failure_charge event_object
      when 'customer.subscription.deleted'
      when 'customer.subscription.updated'
    end
  rescue Exception => ex
    render :json => {:status => 422, :error => "Webhook call failed"}
    return
  end
  render :json => {:status => 200}
end
```

In my routes file I have the following for stripe:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'welcome#index'
  devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: 'users/sessions',
                                    :omniauth_callbacks => "callbacks",
                                    registrations: "users/registrations"}
  resources :profiles
  resources :subscriptions, only: [:new, :create]
  resources :topics, only: [:index, :edit, :create, :destroy, :update]
  resources :topic_profiles, only: [:create, :destroy]
  resources :chats, only: [:index]

  #resources :messages, only: %i[new edit]
  resources :messages, only: %i[new create index]
  post 'incoming_message/webhook'
  resources :test_inbound_messages, only: %i[new create]


  post 'subscription_checkout' => 'subscriptions#subscription_checkout'
  post 'webhook' => 'subscriptions#webhook'
  get 'plans' => 'subscriptions#plans'
  post 'cancel_subscription' => 'subscriptions#cancel_subscription'
  get 'get_cities' => 'profiles#get_cities'
  get 'turn_off_modal'=> "profiles#turn_off_modal"
end
```

I forgot to set up web hooks on the stripe dashboard, its asking me for a URL (`URL to be called`) to enter, according to these routes, what should the url be? im not sure what to use here?

Comment: add hook to receive stripe webhooks (if not already) and listen for `customer.subscription.deleted` event. Since you passed `at_period_end`, that event should trigger when subscription ends (after 10 days) for user. refer - https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/canceling-pausing#events

Comment: web hooks are set up.. I tried `if customer.subscriptions.deleted?` but this doesnot seem to work. I also gave this a try `if customer.subscriptions.retrieve(current_user.subscription_id).deleted?` but nothing

Comment: the event name will be `'customer.subscription.deleted'` which will contain the customer id (which you can then retrieve with `customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(event['customer'])`. at end of subscription, use the event, get the user, and mark `user.subscribed = true`

Comment: I just added my web hook to the question...im not quite sure where your saying to place these and then call `user.subscribed = true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle in `case` of `customer.subscription.deleted`, look below:

```
def webhook
  begin
    event_json = JSON.parse(request.body.read)
    event_object = event_json['data']['object']
    #refer event types here https://stripe.com/docs/api#event_types
    case event_json['type']
      when 'invoice.payment_succeeded'
        handle_success_invoice event_object
      when 'invoice.payment_failed'
        handle_failure_invoice event_object
      when 'charge.failed'
        handle_failure_charge event_object
      when 'customer.subscription.deleted'
        # NOTE HERE, this event will come when stripe actually marks the subscription as canceled, which in your example will be 10 days later.
        # so simply get the user here and mark `subscribed` as false, instead of doing it early
        user = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(event_object['customer'])
        user.update_attribute :subscribed, false
      when 'customer.subscription.updated'
    end
  rescue Exception => ex
    render :json => {:status => 422, :error => "Webhook call failed"}
    return
  end
  render :json => {:status => 200}
end
```

Comment: Iv just updates my question with some more information, As i still havnot got it to work

Comment: doesn't `post 'webhooks' => 'subscriptions#webhooks'` already mean that the correct path of webhook url will be `/webhooks` ?

Comment: in stripe dashboard i have set `http://myapp/webhook` but still nothing seems to work.. for testing i am canceling the subscription from stripe dashboard (immediate cancellation) but still not working, nothing gets changed

Comment: do you get any request(webhook) in your rails with event when you cancel the subscription?

Comment: yh but at the end im getting `Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.` In the stripe dashboard there is a `Signing secret` key i have not used this anywhere in my application which might be why

Comment: add `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:webhook]` in your controller after opening the class.

Comment: that seems to have fixed the CSRF error, but `user.update_attribute :subscribed, false` does not seem to change the subscribed variable to false

Comment: I will leave that for you debug :). Check if the the request is even reaching there, add logs. all the best!